# JDBCTemplate throwing implicit conversion error while executing stored PROC

Tags: sql, sybase, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am trying to execute a Stored PROC as below :

```
String test = "exec insertProc @id=?,@value=?";
jdbcTemplate.update(test,new Object[]{object.getID(),object.getValue()});
```

Table structure :

```
TestTable :
ID varchar(20)
VALUE decimal(6)
```

Error thrown is something like below :

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [exec insertProc @id=?,@value=?]; nested exception is com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybaseException: Implicit conversion from datatype 'VARCHAR' to 'DECIMAL' is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your object.getValue output. Seems its returning a string instead of float i.e. varchar instead of decimal. can you find a sample data set for which its failing?